# Working with two apks as one app

Tags: android, apk, android-library

I have two separate applications but I wanted to use some bits and pieces from one app in my main app. I added another app as library to my main app and I declared intents in the main apps manifest file but I am getting NoClassDefFoundError.

In android world what's the best way to work with multiple apks or libraries?

Please help.

Comment: Are you using multiple akps to targer multiple api levels?

Comment: no I am not targeting multiple api levels, I am trying to use another apps code base as a jar in my main app and include other apps features as part of my main app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use APK Expansion Files. Please visit this link for more explanation.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html